# How can I print out n numbers that satisfy the condition

Tags: java, function, loops, integer

I have written a code that would return either 1 or 4 as the output, and here it is

```
public static int findSum(int k) {
            int sum = 0;
            boolean foundNonZero = false;
            for (; k != 0; k /= 10) {
                if (foundNonZero) {
                    sum += (k % 10)*(k % 10);
                } else {
                    foundNonZero = k % 10 != 0;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

Now, I'm trying to write a function `public static long[] firstK(int k)` that would return `k` numbers starting from 0 that would satisfy the condition that `findsum` = 1.

I'm struggling to understand how to do it, despite reading Java syntax and information. and here is my code so far:

```
public static long[] firstK(int k) {
    while (int x = 0;) {
        if (findSum(x) = 1;)
            System.out.println(x);
        }
```

I know that int(k) isn't used in this, but I have no idea how to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you,
Dave Shah, MUIC

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
public static List<Integer> firstK(int k) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 0 ; result.size() < k ; x++)
        if (findSum(x) == 1)
            result.add(k);
    return result;
}
```

If you really want an array rather than a List, I would still use a List to compute the result.  I would then create an array from that list and return that as the function's result to have the function return a `int[]` or `long[]`.  I can't see why you'd want to return `long[]` or `List<Long>` rather than `int[]` or `List<Integer>`, I doubt the code involved would ever be given the chance to iterate past the maximum integer value.

UPDATE: Here's a complete example that uses an `array` throughout:

```
public class Test {

    public static int findSum(int k) {
        int sum = 0;
        boolean foundNonZero = false;
        for (; k != 0; k /= 10) {
            if (foundNonZero) {
                sum += (k % 10)*(k % 10);
            } else {
                foundNonZero = k % 10 != 0;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static long[] firstK(int k) {
        long[] result = new long[k];
        int i = 0;
        for (int x = 0; i < k; x++)
            if (findSum(x) == 1)
                result[i++] = x;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] r = firstK(5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

The use of an `array` during the operation is fine because you do know the size of that array up front.  You often don't, in which case it is usually cleaner to use a `List` to collect terms, and then convert to an `array` at the end.  I did it this way initially out of habit.  In practice, at least in my case, I pretty much never use arrays due to them being less flexible.  They ARE more compact and can perform better, but it is rarely the case that the difference matters.

Comment: is it possible to do this without changing the type from public static long[] firstK(int k) into public static List<Integer> firstK(int k). I was assigned to do this and its not possible to change the type. Sorryyy